# black video popup shows up on IOS in react native app

Tags: ios, react-native

I have tried this on Android devices and it works fine, but for iOS I am having problems.
I have a iPhone 6 device and when I try to display ads on this device the ads are showing up but along with that after few seconds a black video popup is showing up with default player controls. When I click on close button it hides the black video popup and then I can use the app. The same thing doesn't happen on Android devices or on iPad devices.

I am using below code to show the banner ads

```
<Banner
    adSize= {DSWPConfig.adPolicy.adSize.mediumRectangle}
    validAdSizes={[DSWPConfig.adPolicy.adSize.mediumRectangle]}
    adUnitID={item.adUnitId}
    style = {style?.adStyle}
  />
```